# How to filter the Filelistbox with multiple filetype masking?

Tags: file, delphi, mask

Somehow I need to make a custom "file-open form". 
I manage to retrieve the file list with filelistbox.
My question is when I enter this in filelistbox1.mask

```
Image Files|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png;*.tiff;*.tga
```

all of the *.jpg files did not show up, but other image files ( *.jpeg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png;*.tiff;*.tga) shows up. how come this be ?

I'm sure there is the *.jpg files in the folder, but why the they did not show up in the filelistbox ?

how to fix my mask ? any idea what is the correct mask for it ?

Comment: The `TFileListBox` is designed for Windows 3.1, released in 1992. It looks 'a bit' old. I would *strongly* suggest that you use an ordinary `TListView` or some modern file list box.

Comment: I'm still a delphi beginner... I do not understand how to use TListView....  but anyway thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to list just the extensions.

```
*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png;*.tiff;*.tga
```

At least, that's how I read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/FileCtrl.TFileListBox.Mask).

From the comments it looks like you want to store in the control some friendly text that indicates what type of file the mask refers to, e.g. image files, executable files, text files etc. You could perhaps re-purpose the `Hint` property to do this. You could use the `Tag` property and store a `PChar`. You could derive from `TFileListBox` a new class that contained an extra property. Or you could just store the information in the form class that owns the list box.

Comment: @David. You just beat me to it :)

Comment: @David Heffrnan : that's the previous one I use and it works. But I need to add the words "Image Files" to determine that those are images files. how to add them ?

Comment: I don't understand that comment. The syntax needed for the mask is as per my answer.

Comment: @Sidhi. You are confusing FileListBox which provide the list of files according to the Mask property (without any comment) and File Open Dialog using the Filter property that display the first part (up to "|") as a caption while filtering on the mask (the last part after "|"). You should put a TLabel as a header to your FileListBox as a hint for the content of the file mask.

Comment: anyway I manage to solved it... I just need to add the semicolon ";" after the "|" so it will be "|;"

The complete one should be like this : 

---Image Files|;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png;*.tiff;*.tga;---

working out smooth. Anyway thanks for the help ^^

Comment: How does that solve it? The mask is not visible. We already solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Image Files|`.
It's for the File Dialogs.

Comment: I can not remove the "Image Files|" i need it to determine the files as images (for helping within usage)

Comment: anyway I manage to solved it... I just need to add the semicolon ";" after the "|" so it will be "|;"

The complete one should be like this : 

---Image Files|;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png;*.tiff;*.tga;---

working out smooth. Anyway thanks for the help ^^